# What can mine Ardite and Cobalt?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-tinkers-construct

In Modded Minecraft FTB HermitPack 1.10, the mod "Tinkers' Construct" adds both Cobalt Ore and Ardite Ore. According to the FTB Wiki, to mine these ores, you need a pickaxe "made with Alumite or Steel." However, none of these work:

- Alumite is not available in HermitPack
- Steel pickaxes have a mining level of "Obsidian," which is **not** strong enough to mine either of these ores
- Ardite/Cobalt/Manyullyn pickaxes are not available to me unless I've already mined Ardite/Cobalt ore

Is there any way to mine these ores or otherwise convert them into drops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Obsidian Pickaxe Head** from Tinkers' Construct has a mining level of "Cobalt". So a pickaxe made with an Obsidian head is able to mine both Cobalt and Ardite. (At least in HermitPack 1.2.1)

Obsidian parts can be made in the part builder, for the record.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the FTB wiki page on the obsidian pickaxe is wrong then...

Comment: I suppose FTB wiki is updated by people playing all kinds of different FTB modpacks. I found it to be mostly correct for FTB Infinity Evolved, but for newer or specialized packs it can be glaringly wrong in places. That's simply because it is describing a different pack.

Generally the best source of information in all the packs is NEI (the in-game item list), for Tinkers' Construct you can hold Shift or Ctrl for additional information when hovering over the parts and materials.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried leveling up your tools?
>   *More specifically, have you tried levelling up your Obsidian-level mining tools?*

As part of Iguana Tweaks, when you level up your tool, you obtain a random improvement. One of those improvements increases your mining level, thus allow you to, for example, mine Iron with a Copper Pickaxe).

Comment: I have never seen the tool-leveling give any random improvements except for increasing modifiers, so I don't think this will work